# How can I test data returned from an ajax call in mounted is correctly rendered?

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, axios

I have a component (simplified)

```
<template>
    <div v-if="account">
        <h1 v-text="accountName"></h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import repo from '../../repo';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                account: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            return this.load();
        },
        computed: {
            accountName: function () {
                return this.account.forename + ' ' + this.account.surname;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            load() {
                return repo
                    .get(repo.accounts, {
                        params: {
                            id: this.$route.params.id
                        }
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.account = response.data;
                        this.validateObj = this.account;
                    }, (error) => {

                        switch (error.response.status) {
                            case 403:
                                this.$router.push({name: '403'});
                                break;
                            default:
                                this.$refs['generic_modal'].open(error.message);
                        }

                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Which on mount, calls an API, gets the returned data, and renders the forename and surname.

I'm trying to write a mocha test to check that this works. I can do it using a timeout.

```
it('mounts', done => {

    const $route = {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    };

    mock.onGet('/api/accounts/1').reply(200, {
        forename: 'Tom',
        surname: 'Hart'
    });

    const wrapper = shallowMount(AccountsEdit, {
        i18n,
        mocks: {
            $route
        }
    });

    setTimeout(a => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Tom Hart');
        done();
    }, 1900);
});
```

But I wondered is there a better way? I was hoping to hook into the `axios.get` call, and run the check once that's finished, however, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

EDIT: I tried using $nextTick, however, that didn't work either

```
wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Tom Hart');
    done();
});
```

```
{ Error: expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

Expected substring: "Tom Hart"
Received string:    "<div><h1>undefined undefined</h1></div>"
    at VueComponent.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Dev/V6/Admin/.tmp/mocha-webpack/1554202885644/tests/Javascript/Components/Pages/account-edit.spec.js:37:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Dev/V6/Admin/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1976:12)
    at flushCallbacks (/home/tom/Dev/V6/Admin/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1902:14)
  matcherResult: { message: [Function: message], pass: false } }
{ forename: 'Tom', surname: 'Hart' }
    1) mounts


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Accounts Edit Page
       mounts:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/tom/Dev/V6/Admin/.tmp/mocha-webpack/1554202885644/bundle.js)
```

EDIT 2: It seems just as a test, chaining $nextTick eventually works, so I guess something else is causing ticks before my call returns? Is there anyway to tell what caused a tick to happen?

```
wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
            wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
                wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
                    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
                        wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
                            expect(wrapper.find('h1').html()).toContain('Tom Hart');
                            done();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: would `wrapper.$nextTick` work ? [vuedoc/mounted](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've added to the question the error I get using `$nextTick`

Answer (score 0):

Hey we had similar problem and found this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises

Which allow to us wait all promises before continue testing.
Try to do something like this:

```js
  const flushPromises = require('flush-promises');

  it('mounts', (done) => {
    const $route = {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    };

    mock.onGet('/api/accounts/1').reply(200, {
        forename: 'Tom',
        surname: 'Hart'
    });

    const wrapper = shallowMount(AccountsEdit, {
        i18n,
        mocks: {
            $route
        }
    });

    flushPromises().then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Tom Hart');
        done();
    });
});
```